# Placing a border with top/bottom padding between 2 floated divs of variable height

Tags: html, css, height, css-float

I have some markup:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="one">column a<br />column a</div> 
  <div class="two">column b</div>
</div>
```

Content in the 2 inner divs are of variable height and generated dynamically.

I am just using some standard CSS tricks to give the 2 inner divs the same height:

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}

.two{
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FnWG8/

Problem: While I get a line between the 2 divs, the line extends all the way to the bottom, hitting the container. This is due to not knowing the max height of the 2 inner divs and thus having to use the `padding-bottom: 500px` and `margin-bottom: -500px` trick.

I would like to have the line dividing the 2 inner divs, but there should be some space between the bottom of the line and the containing div:

[image]

What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: why you want the divs to have the same height?

Comment: The divs should have the same height so that I can draw a line between the divs using `border` that will span the whole container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I think it can do what you want:

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.two{
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: try to reduce 1% width of either div

Comment: Problem is now that the 2 columns aren't the same height anymore. There's no way to know which column will be taller or shorter as the content is dynamic.

Comment: but both of them will draw the line, so I suppose it doesn't matter if they are not the same height.

Comment: Good idea! Although, I would prefer something less "hacky" :)

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps

replace this CSS with current one

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.two{
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}​
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. As the inner divs are no longer the same height.

Comment: I have added your code on Fiddle and it worked. Can you please provide the current code. Then we can see and in your CSS you did not define height.

Comment: .container{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height:10px;
    width: 65%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}

.two{
    float: right; 
    height:40px;    
    width: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}​

Try this

Comment: I have not made any changes: Current code is still as per question: http://jsfiddle.net/FnWG8/

Comment: I cannot set a height to the 2 inner divs, because they need to expand depending on the content in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
CSS

```
.container{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    min-height:10px;
    width: 65%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}

.two{
    float: right; 
    min-height:40px;    
    width: 35%;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}​
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't define heights for the 2 inner containers, they need to expand depending on the content in them. Otherwise, I would not have this problem ;)

Comment: use min-height instead of height

Comment: With `min-height`, the problem still persists: border will still hit the bottom of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

change CSS rule labeled ".one" as follows (comment out padding/margin settings)

```
.one{
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    /*padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;*/
}
```

Comment: This causes the 2 inner divs to not be the same height. If `.two` is longer than `.one`, the border does not extend beyond the height of `.one`. Unfortunately, there no way to tell which column will be longer as the content is dynamically generated.